# how to run the program in maximum size in java

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, toolkit

**How to run the program in maximum size in java ,so that it shows the restore button also, without using** 
Toolkit t=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit(); 
**as it doesn't show RestoreDown Button**

Comment: What GUI are you using? `Swing`, `SWT`, `AWT` or other?

Comment: i am using swing @UsagiMiyamoto

Comment: Quit shouting! Bold is used to highlight a word or a phrase, not an entire question.

Comment: i'm a new user And i didn't know that thanks sir for guidance @camickr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
frame.pack();
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto, of course there is. I've been using it will Swing for a decade.

Comment: There is not. It is visible thru `JFrame`, as `JFrame extends Frame`. Most IDEs will hint you to use the declaring class...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto who said you that go and use then talk ,you are here only for decrease others reputation like you have done with me and also with camickr sorry in advance if you get angry

Comment: @HarrySandal `But there is no use of frame.pack isn't it` - I use it in case the user clicks on the "minimuze" button. Then the frame will minimize to the packed size. If you don't do a pack() then it will minimize to just show the titlebar and borders.

Answer (score -1):

If by "run the program in maximum size" you mean open a `JFrame` maximized, then try something like this:

```
setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#setExtendedState-int-

Comment: (1-) this answer was given earlier and there is no need to use the or condition.

Answer (score -2):

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)
```

by using this we can make our screen open in maximize size and it also show us the button for resore-down which is not shown when we use lower one

```
Toolkit t=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension d=t.getScreenSize();
        frame.setLocation((d.width-900),(d.height-600));
```

Comment: (1-) this answer was given earlier. No need to clutter the forum with the same answer.

Comment: Ufff man first use it then say please ..............@UsagiMiyamoto and don't forget to up my reputation if I am Right

Comment: @camick But there is no use of frame.pack isn't it